# How to implement a broadcast receiver on a chat app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am on this chat application project that I've been working on since last month..
I am considering using another alternative way to perform an asynchronous way of checking incoming chat messages.

Is somebody kind enough to share if android broadcast receiver could do this job and if not could you please suggest of something else?